# Can I use an anonymous function with the .map() iterator in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this code to return a new array using .map(). For some reason I cannot figure out how to make the anonymous function work with it. Here is my code. It just returns undefined, smh.

```
const numbers = [2, 7, 9, 171, 52, 33, 14]

const toSquare = num => num * num

// Write your code here:
function squareNums(numArr) {
  numArr.map(num => {
    return (num ** 2);
  })
};

const numberArray = squareNums(numbers);
console.log(numberArray);
```

Comment: You forgot to `return`

Comment: `return numArr.map(toSquare);`

Comment: @MikeM - Yes :-) This is the easy solution, I guess. I was trying to figure out my own function solution though since I'm still learning;

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, it's just your `squareNums` function doesn't *return anything*. In fact, that means it returns *undefined*, which is what you see printed in the console.

Return the result of `numArr.map` instead:

```
function squareNums(numArr) {
-  numArr.map(num => {
+  return numArr.map(num => {
    return (num ** 2);
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I am new at this, so the fact that the function wasn't returning anything never crossed my mind.